# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: email

Tags: react-native

I don't know what is actually happening but the terminal shows the reference error while I run the apps

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: email
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
```

Here is the part that caused this error

```js
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, Input, Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const register = () => {
  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authUser) => {})
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};

const RegisterScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");
```

pls tell me where is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is basically telling you that the `email` (and `password`) variables you are passing to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function do not exist.

You need to declare them, for example:

```js
const email = 'YOUR_FIREBASE_EMAIL';
const password = 'YOUR_FIREBASE_PASSWORD';
const register = () => {
  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authUser) => {})
    .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};
```